# Liferay - Site Page with user customization

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I have a requirement that each user has a different set of portlets that he can see and manage based on his role.

I was initially thinking to model User Pages since I want each user to drag and drop the portlet around and set preferences. But then I realized I cannot have a single user home page and disable portlets based on role since all the portlets on a user page have view permission for "Owner"

Is something like this possible with Community home page. Can I configure a community home page with portlet which has role based permission. Every user will also have an option to drag around or add those portlets on the page and set permissions. I doubt I can give common access to all the user add portlet permission on the community page, since the page will be loaded with portlets.

In that case can I use the first approach and have flexibility to show set of portlets on user home page (private page) based on certain role and not have "Owner Role" interfere.

Comment: Isn't it a usecase for "User's personal site" feature of Liferay?

Comment: Yes I want User's personal site to be pre-configured with different portlets as upfront. User A on login has A, B, C portlet and User B on login has A,C, E portlet where B can be seen only by role x and E can be seen by only role y. A and C can be seen by any role. Since these pages have to be pre configured, it can be done using a page template or property. One page template or set of properties can only be applied to one page

Comment: I see. Then it would be best to control their rendering either using the portlet themselves OR using theme - depending on your choice.